# What did Julius Lippert lecture on after WWII?

Tags: germany

[Julius Lippert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Lippert) was a Nazi top functionary (mayor of Berlin till he was demoted and fell out of grace) and a convicted war criminal. However, wiki tells us:

> He lectured at universities until his death on 30 June 1956, in Bad
>   Schwalbach.

What did he lecture about? Where?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.luise-berlin.de/historie/spitze/zukap4/juliuslippert.htm):

> Bis zu seinem Tode hat Julius Lippert in Bad Schwalbach Vorträge über Kunstgeschichte gehalten.

Translation mine:

> Until his death, Julius Lippert held lectures on art history in Bad Schwalbach.

---

The location seems inconsistent ("at universities" -- "in Bad Schwalbach", perhaps they confused location of death with the location of his lectures), but at least the subject seems clear - art history.